# Extending typescript interface

Tags: interface, typescript

When extending the Express.Request interface in TypeScript I ran into this problem that I want to use an external library definition, but I can't import the external library as it results in error ->

Error:(4, 28) TS1147: Import declarations in an internal module cannot reference an external module.

Edit: It is a .d.ts file

```
/// <reference path="../typings/express/express.d.ts" />

declare module Express {
    import bunyan = require('bunyan'); <-- results in error
    export interface Request {
        _id: string; <-- this works
        log: bunyan.Logger; <-- Here I want to define that it is bunyan.Logger instance;
    }
}
```

Trying to reference the bunyan.d.ts (https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/bunyan/bunyan.d.ts)
Also results in a problem, as the bunyan module is exported as string

```
declare module "bunyan" {
...
}
```

As such trying to use it from reference results in not found.

```
/// <reference path="../typings/express/express.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../typings/bunyan/bunyan.d.ts" />

declare module Express {
    export interface Request {
        _id: string;
        log: bunyan.Logger; <- Error:(8, 18) TS2304: Cannot find name 'bunyan'.
    }
}
```

tl;dr; How to extend interface definition with external module definitions.

Comment: Why `declare` in `declare module Express`?

Comment: @Tarh
Error:(4, 1) TS1046: A 'declare' modifier is required for a top level declaration in a .d.ts file.

Comment: OK. The `require` misled me, I believed it was a `.ts` file.

Comment: A suggestion: if a file `.d.ts` exists for the external module `bunyan`, you can reference it with `/// <reference ...` and then use it to type `Request.log`.

Comment: External modules are not namespaces. Try to use `Logger` instead of `bunyan.Logger`. If it still not works, then you can try to upgrade to typescript 1.5-alpha and to use the external module import syntax. Or edit the `.d.ts` file and remove the quotes in `declare module "bunyan"` => `declare module bunyan`. Without quotes, `bunyan` becomes a namespace and `bunyan.Logger` becomes available.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can add to an existing interface when a `require` is necessary, but you can extend the existing interface using the `extends` keyword.

Move your import statement outside your module, export your module, and extend the existing interface:

```
import bunyan = require('bunyan');
import express = require('express');

export declare module ExtendedExpress {
    export interface Request extends express.Express.Request {
        _id: string;
        log: bunyan.Logger;
    }
}
```

Then you have to import this module where you want to use it.

Comment: Adding an import outside the declare function causes all the extensions being lost. (The fail is as if not referenced at all)

Error:(71, 9) TS2339: Property '_id' does not exist on type 'Request'.

Comment: Yes, I can extend this way creating a new interface with a different name. Not what I want though -> The express module has internal RequestHandler interface that uses the Request interface. By creating a new interface I would have to import and define on every route handler that the parameters are of the new interface not the old - very cumbersome. Whereas extending the old interface gives me this information automatically.

Comment: @DeadAlready if you really want to do what you want, then I think you have to edit the original `express.d.ts` directly. There's a few guys who frequent the `typescript` tag and they're more knowledge than me on this so they'll probably be able to give a more definitive answer.

Answer (score 1):

The referencing of internal and external modules will be improved in v1.5 which is currently in an alpha release (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/typescript/archive/2015/03/27/announcing-typescript-1-5-alpha.aspx).

In the meantime you can import in your `bunyan` module via:

```
var bunyan = require('bunyan');
```

Comment: Error:(4, 16) TS1039: Initializers are not allowed in ambient contexts.