# How to declare TypeScript type interface for custom meta fields in Vue Router v4?

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vue-router, vuejs3, vue-router4

With **Vue Router version 4**, which is currently [in beta.11 in vue-router-next repo](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next), there is a [documentation page](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-router-next/blob/2b7300ba2b48e5a2f3729deff77a53cf9ecb4838/docs/guide/advanced/meta.md#typescript) about **how to define meta fields custom type interface with TypeScript**.

```
declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface RouteMeta {
    // is optional
    isAdmin?: boolean
    // must be declared by every route
    requiresAuth: boolean
  }
}
```

To be placed along the Vue shim module declaration. Mine is looking like:

```
declare module '*.vue' {
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

  const component: ReturnType<typeof defineComponent>;
  export default component;
}

declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface RouteMeta {
    isPublic?: boolean;
  }
}
```

However, this is not working. Instead this way of defining the interface seems to overwrite the interface that is shipped with the package, or rather declaring 'vue-router' module seems to do that.

**What would be the correct way of defining custom meta field types?**

Comment: Because their documentation is wrong or incomplete. That snippet, as documented does exactly what _you_ say. It supplants the declarations for the `'vue-router'` package with your own instead of augmenting them. To fix, move `declare module 'vue-router'` to a separate file, and make that file a module by beginning it with `export {}`. Those two `declare module` blocks cannot exist in the same file because one of them is trying to declare a module and the other to augment one.

Comment: Thanks @AluanHaddad, this seems to have solved the problem. Moved these declarations to separate files. But how does adding `export {};` statement before `declare module 'vue-router'` block change it from overwriting the package's module declaration to augmenting it instead?

Comment: I added some documentation links in the answer. Basically the difference in meaning is that `import`/`export` change the meaning of a file from script to module. And the syntax for declaring and augmenting is the same but means one thing in one context and another in the other.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Their documentation is wrong or at best incomplete.

A [Module Augmentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#module-augmentation) uses the same syntax as an [Ambient Module](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#ambient-modules)  declaration and is only considered an augmentation when it is within a module file itself. A module is defined, as per the ECMAScript specification, as a file containing one or more top level `import` or `export` statements.

The snippet in a file that is not a module does exactly what *you*'ve noticed. It supplants any other type declarations for the `'vue-router'` package instead of augmenting them. But we want to augment that package's types, not replace them.

However, a `declare module` statement that is intended as a declaration, not an augmentation, must be in a file that is, conversely, not a module. That is, in a file ***not*** containing any top level `import` or `export` statements.

To resolve this, move the `declare module 'vue-router' {...}` to a separate file (say, `augmentations.d.ts`), and make that file a module by beginning it with `export {}`.

```js
// augmenations.d.ts

// Ensure this file is parsed as a module regardless of dependencies.
export {}

declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface RouteMeta {
    // is optional
    isAdmin?: boolean
    // must be declared by every route
    requiresAuth: boolean
  }
}
```

Now let's come back and take look at the original code in question.

```
// shims-vue.d.ts

declare module '*.vue' {
  import { defineComponent } from 'vue';

  const component: ReturnType<typeof defineComponent>;
  export default component;
}

declare module 'vue-router' {
  interface RouteMeta {
    isPublic?: boolean;
  }
}
```

The two `declare module` statements cannot exist in the same file because one of them is trying to declare a module, `'*.vue'`, and the other to augment one. Therefore, we will leave the `declare module '*.vue' {...}` where it is, as it is functioning as intended.

Answer (score 0):

I put the file router.ts into a types dir,which is on the same level with src,then i  modify the tsconfig.json  "include": ["src/**/*.ts", "src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.vue","types/**/*.ts"],and it works

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).