# Vue 3 TypeScript error "Module vue has no exported..."

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuetify.js, vite, vue-composition-api

I'm having TypeScript error where it doesn't find Vue types. I tried modifying list of tsconfig.* that I have in my project but I could not figure out exactly what I need to do to fix this.

[**Here is the full reproduction if you need**](https://github.com/kevinmnm/vue3-composition-api-ts-error-reproduction)

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: Shouldn't you be extending the vue runtime-core interface instead of redefining it here? https://github.com/kevinmnm/vue3-composition-api-ts-error-reproduction/blob/master/src/types/global.d.ts

Comment: @ChaseDeAnda Thanks! I just had to put `import '@vue/runtime-core'` to fix the issue.

Comment: Here's a related question and answer with a fair amount of explanation and some suggested conventions https://stackoverflow.com/a/63999522/1915893