# Add Axios as a plugin in Vue/Typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript, vue.js, axios, vuetify.js

I've been trying to add Axios to the Vue prototype so I can access it as `this.$http`. I'm using Typescript so I need the type definitions for this too. I've seen plenty of places on the internet that describe how to do this, but no matter what I try, Typescript doesn't recognise my definitions and I get the error:

`Property '$http' does not exist on type`

I think it's something to do with my `tsconfig.json`, but I'm not sure. Please see below the relevant files:

src/plugins/axios.ts

```
import _Vue from 'vue';
import Axios from 'axios';

export function AxiosPlugin<AxiosPlugOptions>(
  Vue: typeof _Vue,
  options?: AxiosPluginOptions,
): void {
  Vue.prototype.$http = Axios.create({
    baseURL: options?.baseUrl,
  });
}

export class AxiosPluginOptions {
    baseUrl = '';
}
```

src/types/axios-plugin.d.ts

```
import { AxiosStatic } from 'axios';

declare module 'vue/types/vue' {
    export interface Vue {
        $http: AxiosStatic;
    }
}
```

src/main.ts

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import App from './App.vue';
import router from './router';
import store from './store';
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';
import { AxiosPlugin } from './plugins/axios';

Vue.config.productionTip = false;

Vue.use(AxiosPlugin, {
  baseUrl: 'https://localhost:44390/api/',
});

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  vuetify,
  render: (h) => h(App),
}).$mount('#app');
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "strict": true,
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types",
      "./node_modules/vuetify/types",
    ],
    "types": [
      "webpack-env",
      "vuetify"
    ],
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "src/*",
      ],
    },
    "lib": [
      "esnext",
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "scripthost"
    ]
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.ts",
    "src/**/*.tsx",
    "src/**/*.vue",
    "tests/**/*.ts",
    "tests/**/*.tsx"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ]
}
```

Does anyone know why my type declaration is not being recognised?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extending typescript interface](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29516522/extending-typescript-interface)

Comment: I don't think so. I'm trying to do what is described here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43142304/10623675
But I can't get it to work as described. I think it's got something to with my tsconfig having typeRoots and types defined, so I have to include them manually, but haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: is it fixed by adding `src/**/*.d.ts` to your include list in tsconfig.ts?